# Multipart form data is not working in spring 4.3.5 RELEASE rest api

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc

I am creating an api which consume multipart/form-data in spring

```
@PostMapping(value="/upload",consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
     public ResponseEntity<byte[]> uploadFile(@RequestParam("name") String name,
             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
}
```

But when  calling this api from POSTMAN . I am getting bad request "Required String parameter 'name' is not present"

[image]

Comment: Show how you are calling it

Comment: Add them in 'params' tab and see

Comment: but i need to call via form data only .... how i can i include file in params

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@RequestPart` for the file parameter.

Comment: i tried it with @RequestPart but getting same error "Required request part 'name' is not present"